# Make NFS connection use LAN when available, and VPN otherwise

Tags: networking, vpn, nfs, wireguard

I have a desktop/workstation running FreeBSD, and a laptop running Windows 11 Pro. I'd like to use NFS to allow me to access my workstation files from my laptop. That itself is totally fine: Windows 11 Pro supports NFS, and I have a wireguard VPN that allows me to access my workstation when I'm not at home. The problem is, that wireguard VPN goes through a virtual private server that is hosted on the public internet (my workstation is behind a router at home), and when I'm physically at home, I'd rather not send all my NFS traffic out to the VPS and then back to my house. I'm not an expert on networking - what's the best way to accomplish this? I have the vague sense that I could probably solve this by hosting my own DNS server, but before I dig too deeply into what that entails, I thought I'd see if someone more knowledgeable than I has a better idea.

I suppose I could also set up two separate NFS mounts, one for LAN and one for VPN...

Comment: Have you considered using SMB3 instead? From what I've heard, the SMB3 client in Windows is far more advanced than the NFS client _(Unicode? Kerberos?)_, and in particular I suspect its support for SMB Multichannel might help you here.

Comment: I hadn't considered it, but I will look into how good the support is on the FreeBSD side. Interesting idea. Thank you.

Comment: On the FreeBSD side, you have Samba which is a reliable SMB server. (But admittedly I've never actually used its Multichannel features, only known that they exist.) And, I *think* NFSv4.2 has something similar, but unfortunately NFS is kind of a competitor to SMB, so Microsoft has close to no interest in improving Windows' NFS support...